# writing a test case for a function in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test case for the following function:

```
export function exportTableToCSV(data, columns, filename) {
    const csv = encode(data, columns);
    downloadCsv(csv, filename);
}
```

And here the test case:

```
exportTableToCSV = jest.fn();
it('testing exportTableToCSV function', () => {
    const data = {
        "Linkname": "ATL-HOU",
        "Anode": "ATL:pos0/1",
        "Aloc": "ATL"
    }
    const columns = Object.keys(data);
    const filename = "data.csv";
    exportTableToCSV(data,columns,filename);
    expect(exportTableToCSV).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data,columns,filename);
}
```

this works but when try to add:

```
expect(encode).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data,columns);
```

it gives me an error saying it was not called.
can someone please guide me what is the correct way to write testcase for above function

Comment: Please share the complete code file where `exportTableToCSV` is defined, thanks.  (Or at least include the function definitions for `encode` and `downloadCSV`, how those functions are defined determines how you mock them)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `exportTableToCSV` which is called is not the real `exportTableToCSV`, it is a `jest.fn()`. The real `exportTableToCSV` will invoked `encode()`, but you aren't using the real one here, so `encode()` isn't invoked.

One solution I would try would be to import the real `exportTableToCSV()` and have `encode()` as a `jest.fn()`. Then, when you call `exportTableToCSV()`, expect `encode()` to have been called and you will prove that both were invoked.

Here's one way to do that:

```
import { exportTableToCSV } from './foo'

it('testing exportTableToCSV function', () => {
  const mockEncodeResult = 'i am a mock';
  const encode = jest.fn((data, columns) => mockEncodeResult);
  const downloadCsv = jest.fn((csv, filename) => {});

  const testData = {
    Linkname: 'ATL-HOU',
    Anode: 'ATL:pos0/1',
    Aloc: 'ATL',
  };

  const testColumns = Object.keys(testData);
  const testFilename = 'data.csv';

  exportTableToCSV(testData, testColumns, testFilename);

  expect(encode).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testData, testColumns);
  expect(downloadCsv).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockEncodeResult, testFilename);
});
```

Please note: In the above example I do not mock `exportTableToCSV`. `jest.fn()` is a mock. This unit test imports and tests the real `exportTableToCSV` function, but it mocks `encode()` and `downloadCsv()`. Cheers!

UPDATE ---

Per your comment you state you are seeing an error about `createObjectURL`, but this is not in the sample code provided. Clearly, then, there is some problematic code in the module you are importing along with `exportTableToCSV`. The proper way to fix this is to mock and clean that problematic code, but because I want to provide a self-contained solution here, a second-best approach is to mock `exportTableToCSV` itself. In this case you will not test the original function, but only the mock. Remove the `import` statement and add the following inside the scope of the test case, after the definition of `downloadCsv`:

```
const exportTableToCSV = jest.fn((data, columns, filename) => {
  const csv = encode(data, columns);
  downloadCsv(csv, filename);
});
```

Comment: can you guide me on how to mock a function?meaning how can i mock exportTableToCSV function?

Comment: updated with example code. also see [the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html). Best wishes!

Comment: I added another detail to make it more clear: in the above example I do not mock `exportTableToCSV`, but I do mock the other functions which are invoked from within.

Comment: I agree! You can write different tests for those underlying functions. If my answer helped you then please up-vote and accept.

Comment: i understood your concept. But the test case still gives error as typeError window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Comment: I added an update to my answer to address your new comment

Comment: Thanks John. the updated one; can you explain me the working and is it a valid approach for writing unit test cases?

Comment: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)
    
    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [{"Aloc": "ATL", "Anode": "ATL:pos0/1", "Linkname": "ATL-HOU"}, "data.csv"]
    But it was not called